# 2014 peugeot boxer start issues

Tags: starting, peugeot, boxer

hoping someone can help.
Recently purchased a 2014 boxer to convert to camper. After leaving it overnight it takes 2-3 attempts to start but once it's started once its fine the rest of the day.

A local garage recomended changing EGR valve (code was showing) but this didnt change anything so they suspected the battery was bad. Replaced this too and i'm still having issues.

It does occasionally start up in the morning when I hit the accelarator but im not sure if this is a conincidence or not.

Glow plug light comes on and goes out pretty quickly and i always let it sit on for 30 secs before turning over.

Any ideas what could be causing it? Or what i can check to help diagnose?
Thanks!

Comment: If you turn the key to on (not start) three times, (off --> on -->off-->on-->off-->on, then --> start) does it then start immediately?  if so, the check valve in the fuel pump is stuck open.  The fuel is draining from the engine back to the tank when the vehicle is shut off for the night.

Answer (score 0):

I am not an expert here, but after reading your situation it is pretty clear there seems to be a problem with the fueling system. You won't know which component(s) is at fault unless you do further diagnostics. Since it's a diesel as long as there is fuel and air it will run, rough or not. Like zipzit said it might be the check valve(s), check your car's service manual or online resources to find where they are. If there is a Shrader valve somewhere in line before you start the car, depress it to see if there is fuel pressure. Obviously, it is better if you can just put an fuel gauge inline, and just check that way. Because if you find out your fuel pressure is low, you can confirm that the prediction is accurate. Even better if you have a scan tool that shows you the on-time fuel pressure. If the pressure is fine, the check valves are fine and there is pressure overnight, it might be a sticky injector which you can do a buzz test to confirm. Or maybe it needs a bleed... there are some possibilities, Hopefully, it's the check valve.